# Spaces are not recognized correctly in the TipTap Editor

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend, tiptap

we use the rich text editor of TipTap in our project.
But we have the problem, that spaces are not recognized correctly and only after every 2 click a space is created. As framework we use Vue.JS.

```
import { Editor, EditorContent, EditorMenuBar } from 'tiptap'
import {
  HardBreak,
  Heading,
  OrderedList,
  BulletList,
  ListItem,
  Bold,
  Italic,
  History
} from 'tiptap-extensions'
import EditorMenuButton from './EditorMenuButton.vue'
export default {
  name: 'editor',
  components: {
    EditorMenuButton,
    EditorMenuBar,
    EditorContent
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: null,
      default: ' '
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      innerValue: ' ',
      editor: new Editor({
        extensions: [
          new HardBreak(),
          new Heading({ levels: [1, 2, 3] }),
          new BulletList(),
          new OrderedList(),
          new ListItem(),
          new Bold(),
          new Italic(),
          new History()
        ],
        content: `${this.innerValue}`,
        onUpdate: ({ getHTML }) => {
          this.innerValue = getHTML()
        }
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // Handles internal model changes.
    innerValue (newVal) {
      this.$emit('input', newVal)
    },
    // Handles external model changes.
    value (newVal) {
      this.innerValue = newVal
      this.editor.setContent(this.innerValue)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if (this.value) {
      this.innerValue = this.value
      this.editor.setContent(this.innerValue)
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    this.editor.destroy()
  }
}
</script>
```

does anyone have any idea what could be the reason for assuming only every two spaces?

Comment: Your chances of getting a useful answer without a [mcve] (***actually** reproducing the behavior*) are close to `null`. Use codesandbox.io or any other online multi-file node based editor. What you've shown here does not reproduce the described behavior and is missing: the template and the contents of `EditorMenuButton.vue` (most likely where your bug is coming from).

Comment: [Here's a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-kilby-ysvnd?file=/src/components/Editor.vue) with what you've shown so far. As you can see, it's working as expected. So, please, add the bug to it so someone could debug it. :) Note: I did make some changes, because you can't init the editor in `data`. Do it in `mounted`, as in their examples. [Here's why](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

Comment: thank you we will try to program it in the code sandbox

Comment: @tao initializing the editor in `data` is exactly how it's written in the [examples](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/examples/Components/Routes/Basic/index.vue#L167).

Comment: @Erich, with the notable difference in the linked example it's not using `this` inside `data`. Because it's not available. Which is why I suggested moving it in `mounted`.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem, we kept the `onUpdate` trigger but changed the watch so that it would only invoke `editor.setContent` when the value was actually different.

```
  watch: {
    value() {
      let html = this.editor.getHTML();
      if (html !== this.value) {
        this.editor.setContent(this.value);
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Remove onUpdate section and the bug will disapear. I don't know why, but it's interesting to know how to reproduce the bug.*

That does help. Following this advice, I am currently using the `onBlur` event instead of `onUpdate`, while obtaining the content's HTML using the editor instance and the `getHTML()` function, as such: `this.editor.getHTML()`.

*(In my case I `$emit` this value in order for it to be reactive to my parent component, but that may be irrelevant for the original question).*

Comment: This solved the issue for me. 

Replacing:
```
const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    content: message,
    onUpdate: ({ editor }) => { // <-- This line
      setMessage(editor.getHTML());
    },
  });
```

with this:
```
  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit, SensitiveContent],
    content: message,
    onBlur: ({ editor }) => { // <-- This line
      setMessage(editor.getHTML());
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

"Okay the problem is that the watcher will get fired when you type in the editor. So this will check if the editor has focus an will only update the editor content if that's not the case."

```js
 watch: {
    value(val) {
      if (!this.editor.focused) {
        this.editor.setContent(val, false);
      }
    }
  },
```

issue: https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/776#issuecomment-667077233

Answer (score 0):

This bug for me was caused by doing something like this:

```
  watch: {
    value: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newValue) {
        this.editor.setContent(newValue)
      },
    },
  },
```

Removed this entirely and the bug went away. Maybe this will help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this.

```
watch: {
    // Handles external model changes.
    value (newVal) {
        // convert whitespace into \u00a0 -> &nbsp;
        let content = newVal.replace(/\s/g, "\u00a0");
        this.editor.setContent(content)
    }
},
```

It seems like the normal white space has been removed by html automatically. Therefore, I convert whitespace into 'nbsp;' and it's worked.

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided seems to be working just fine. So the issue most likely is produced by a side effect in either your code or some dependency.

To debug this issue you could look for event listeners, especially regarding key press or key down events and looking if you are checking for space key specifically somewhere (`event.keyCode === 32` or `event.key === " "`). In conjunction with `event.preventDefault` this could explain such an issue.

Another more broad way to debug this is to strip away parts from your code until the bug disappears or add to a minimal example until the bug appears.

Answer (score -1):

Remove onUpdate section and the bug will disapear. I don't know why, but it's interessing to know how to reproduce the bug. 
However if you create a "minimal reproductible example" the bug does not appear. 
So what ? I don't know.

I found a workaround which is to use vuex.

Rather than assign the value returned by getHTML() in the innerValue variable and then issue an 'input' event, I put this value in the store.